# What's the best HTTP status code for a redirect from / to /home?

Tags: http, redirect, http-headers, url-routing, http-status-codes

I have a web application where the requested URL is used in a REST-like fashion. However, if no URL is entered (just the domain) I re-direct to `http://www.example.com/home` and then my home controller is loaded.

What HTTP status code should I use for this re-direct? This process takes place in my `index.php` script using a simple `header('Location: home')` call.

**Clarification:** this may not be permanent, but will remain present in this version of the application. So for example, if this application were to be redeveloped in the future then the new developer may chose to once again serve requests from the root. I would imagine this then narrows my choices to:

- `303 See Other`
- `307 Moved Temporarily`

Comment: Even `index.php` could be called from various URI "directory". Therefor you should use `header('Location: /home')`.

Comment: @Wernight actually, the `Location` header expects an absolute URI (see [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30)), so it should be `header('Location: http://www.example.com/home')`

Comment: @Bruno: Yes you're right. I just found that it always worked with relative URLs too. I wonder when the absolute URL is **required**; but that's another question.

Comment: Make sure response contains a hyperlink to the new URI as well in case request is GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd favor 302 "Found" for this use; that tells the user-agent that they can/should continue requesting `/` in the future because someday the redirect might be different. (But I could make a case for 301 "Moved Permanently", too.)

Comment: Yeah. My reasoning was I didn't want to break it if in the future requests were able to be served from the root of the domain again.

Comment: If you don't send a Cache-Control or Expire header as well then issuing 302 is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

based on http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html 1 would say 301, Moved Permanently

Answer (score 0):

Code 301. After some time 410 (If you want requesters not to reference deprecated URL in their code).